# dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS

Tags: java, unix, fedora, dlopen, thread-local-storage

I have a large mixed java/c++ application that loads multiple shared libs into java. It works fine on my Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit machine, but I'm having problems getting things to work on a Fedora 17 64-bit machine. Everything compiles fine, but when I try to run it I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /pathto/libmylib.so: dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:
I've narrowed this down to a problem with PCL (point cloud library) dependencies. libmylib.so depends on PCL, but can also be compiled without PCL if it's not installed. Compiling without PCL works fine. I'm waiting on the folks in the PCL community to get back to me, and I'll update this thread based on their suggestions.

Comment: I removed the C++ tag since this is either a Java or linker/loader question, not C++.

Comment: Does it behave the same regardless of whether you build `libmylib.so` on Ubuntu or Fedora?

Comment: Do you mean build libmylib.so on Ubuntu and use that lib on Fedora?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like PCL library depends on `libgomp`, and you are likely hitting [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2012-04/msg01319.html) issue.