# Cannot load any more object with static TLS

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, ubuntu, dlopen

I have an application that use `dlopen()` to load additional modules. The application and modules are built on Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64 using gcc 4.6 but for i386 arch. The binaries are then copied to another machine with exactly same OS and work fine.

However if they are copied to Ubuntu 12.04 i386 then some (but not all) modules fail to load with the following message:

```
dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS
```

I would suspect that this is caused by the usage of `__thread` variables. However such variables are not used in the loaded modules - only in the loader module itself.

Can someone provide any additional info, what can be the reason?

I am reducing number of `__thread` variables and optimizing them (with `-ftls-model` etc), I'm just curious why it doesn't work on *almost* same system.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650740/dlopen-cannot-load-any-more-object-with-static-tls

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I would suspect that this is caused by the usage of __thread variables.

Correct.

> However such variables are not used in the loaded modules - only in the loader module itself.

Incorrect. You may not be using `__thread` yourself, but some library you statically link in into your module *is* using them. You can confirm this with:

```
readelf -l /path/to/foo.so | grep TLS
```

> what can be the reason?

The module is using `-ftls-model=initial-exec`, but should be using `-ftls-model=global-dynamic`. This most often happens when (some of) the code linked into `foo.so` is built without `-fPIC`.

Linking non`-fPIC` code into a shared library is impossible on `x86_64`, but is allowed on `ix86` (and leads to many subtle problems, like this one).

**Update:**

> I have 1 module compiled without -fPIC, but I do not set tls-model at all, as far as I remember the default value is not initial-exec

- There could only be one tls model for each ELF image (executable or shared library).
- TLS model defaults to `initial-exec` for non`-fPIC` code.

It follows that if you link even one non`-fPIC` object that uses `__thread` into `foo.so`, then `foo.so` gets `initial-exec` for *all* of its TLS.

> So why it causes problems - because if initial-exec is used then the number of tls variables is limited (because they are not dynamically allocated)?

Correct.

Comment: I do not fully understand. I have 1 module compiled without -fPIC (I was experimenting with performance), but I do not set tls-model at all, as far as I remember the default value is not initial-exec? So why it causes problems - because if initial-exec is used then the number of tls variables is limited (because they are not dynamically allocated)? I already resolved my problems by reducing number of __thread vars (they were in .h header used in few modules, I put all into single one) and the error is gone, but I'm still curious.